# Writing a script that gives how much lines have "X" and "Y" in it?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm doing a course in Linguistic and I would like to use shell scripts to help me doing few repetitive things such as counting who asks questions.
Here is part of the file I opened and work with the `gedit` command

> *Antoine: Il a du*
>
> *Eliahou:(Eliahou se penche) Chez Ubisoft? T'as du faire la queue?*
>
> *Delmas: Non j'ai pas fait d'queue.*
>
> *Eliahou: directement ils t'ont donné ça, t'es arrivé...*
>
> *Antoine: //Bonjour je voudrai un lapin-crétin.*
>
> *Delmas: Eu::f//, Euh un 'tit speech quand même.*
>
> *Eliahou: Ha, tu leur a parlé °(quand même un peu)?*
>
> *Delmas: Oui bien sûr.*

I'm looking for writing a general script that gives how much lines have "X"  and "Y" in it? 
I'm looking, for instance on how to write a script that gives the name and the number of occurence of names a associated with a variable. For instance in the dialogue Eliahou asks two questions.

More precisely:

- who asks questions (who have a "?" in their quote), how much time
- who cut someone off, (who have a "//" in their quote)
- who repeats somebody sentences
- who does some elision ("t'es" instead of "tu es" ("you're" instead of
  "you are") and at which frequency...

For the first one I thought about

```
# usage nbocc String File
grep $1 $2 >temp
wc -l <temp
rm temp
```

its result is:

```
MyComputer:~$ sh compteurQuestions ? Communication
8
```

Yet, I don't have the people with such a command... How should I do then to have them?

I know I should use

```
^........
```

because the maximal length of a name here is 8. But this is quite a brutal approach, I'm looking for a more elegant

I tried with the awsome script given by Jay jargo, yet it seems that there is an issue as far as after writing with the actual text `$ compteurQuestions -v s="?" exempleCommunication`, I get `Delmas 12 0`. However, Delmas asked at least one question: `Delmas : ils l’ont plié ?`

#### the actual text

> (Tout le monde est assis face à la caméra sauf Matthieu)  Antoine:
>   Allumlalum...Elal...
>
> Eliahou: c'est mieux pour toi! c'est mieux pour toi!
>
> Matthieu: Mais t'inquiè::::te!
>
> Eliahou:* Il est allumé là?
>
> Antoine: * Allume //Matthieu: Ca, C'est bon, ça// sinon sinon [Antoine
>   se lève] // Matthieu:* Non mais, on s'voit tous, y a rien qui va
>   bouger, t'inquiète assieds-toi. * Non mais //Matthieu: Mais ça va pas
>   bouger.// non, mais au moins pour vérifier.
>
> Eliahou: Non, non laisse le //Matthieu: Regarde on bouge pas non plus
>   [Matthieu s'assoit]// non, non mais c'est mieux qu'on se voit.
>   //Antoine: Si si// nan, nan
>
> Matthieu: C'est trop perturbant //[Eliahou pointe l'écran du doigt]//
>
> Antoine: La dernière fois qu'on, la dernière fois on l'a pas fait
>   [Antoine touche à l'ordinateur] //Matthieu: Haaaa Nan Haaa Je vois un
>   écran là//
>
> Antoine: [Antoine présente un lapin-crétin] Les amis j'vous présente
>   Bob, Bob le gri-gri.
>
> Delmas: C'est un cadeau du Forum.
>
> Antoine: Salut les amis, Hey!(il lève un sourcil) Tiens, on te passe
>   le grigri, celui qui a le grigri a le droit de parler //Matthieu:
>   Quand tu sais combien...// [Delmas prend le lapin-crétin, Matthieu
>   suit du regard]
>
> Eliahou: Tu l'as eu au forum, genre [il point le gri-gri du doigt]? //
>
> Antoine: C'est lui qui a la parole. [Antoine pointe Delmas du doigt]//
>
> Delmas: Oui chez Ubisoft.
>
> Antoine:* Il a dû…
>
> Eliahou: [se penche] * Chez Ubisoft? T'as du faire la queue?
>
> Delmas: Non j'ai pas fait d'queue.
>
> Eliahou: directement ils t'ont donné ça, t'es arrivé... //Antoine:
>   Bonjour je voudrais un lapin-crétin.// //Delmas: Eu::f,// Euh un 'tit
>   speech quand même.
>
> Eliahou: Ha, tu leur a parlé quand même un peu?
>
> Delmas: Oui bien sûr.
>
> Eliahou: A la fin ils t'ont dit, “Non on a pas besoin de toi” et après
>   tu leur as [il fait un geste pour ramener quelque chose vers soi]
>   “Chpeux prendre quand même ça.” C'est ça.
>
> Delmas: Voilà. [signe de la main gauche qui se lève et retombe]
>
> Antoine: Bonjour Delmas apprenti lapin crétin //Delmas: Nan mais,
>   [écarte le bras gauche et fait non de la tête] après le Forum ça sert
>   presque à rien, ils ne veulent que des des// des longs si... Et des
>   trucs de six mois. [acquiesce et lève les yeux]
>
> Delmas: //Ouai, voilà.
>
> Eliahou: Ah six mois, ah ouai? Hier chui parti [Delmas remonte ses
>   lunettes et se gratte le nez] avec une personne qui voulait ...euh...
>   pas faire de stage là bas, Juste ramasser des petits gadgets nan mais
>   vraiment, yen a ya des personnes, [ Delmas lève le doigt) et tu
>   lai...//Antoine: huhu!!! c'est vrai?//
>
> Matthieu: r'garde Mohammed, tout à l'heure il est revenu avec du
>   liquide vaisselle.
>
> Antoine: HAHAHA! [se tape la cuisse] il aurait [lève le doigt] même pu
>   passer chez Etam lu grpus au pus [doigt index]
>
> Matthieu: J'ai J'ai même envoyé un sms à Mariam, tu pouvais même
>   trouver à bouffer, le Printemps ils ont ramené à bouffer
>
> Eliahou: Sérieux? (interloqué) Putain, holala //Delmas: Pffft! (tête
>   sur le côté) Euuuuh La vérité, Hier j'y étais mais pas //pour
>   ramasser//
>
> Antoine: (inaudible) tu dis la vérité, Hinhinhin
>
> Eliahou: la vérité... [écarte de temps en temps les mains] nan sérieux
>   j'y étais hier et puis moi chui parti pour trouver un stage, 'fin pour
>   trouver un stage, pour essayer de ramasser un peu des gadgets aussi.
>
> Antoine: Hin Hin Hin! Vas-y, nous t'écoutons... //Eliahou: Et puis
>   baaah, dès que t'arrives ya énormément de monde, c'est assez frustrant
>   t'as po envie de faire la queue// toi tu veux ton p'tit gadget, ^(ton
>   petit lapin-crétin) hin hin hin? //Eliahou: Et j'veux tout de suite
>   mon p'tit gadget. E::::t puis euh dès que j'arrive à un moment chui
>   arrivé jusqu'au bout du du forum e:::t yavait personne, ché plus
>   c'était qui quelle société ils cherchaientt des stagiaires. Donc euuh,
>   mais bon...j'me demandais
>
> Antoine: Ca m'parait louche [pointe Eliahou du doigt], là louche
>
> Eliahou: Ca m'paraissait louche.
>
> Antoine: Ca m'paraissait louche [pointe le doigt vers le ciel]
>
> Eliahou : je leur ai laissé mon cv euhhhh , ils l’ont gardé , ils
>   l’ont plié , ils l’ont mit de coté et j’suis parti
>
> Antoine : euh euh les cv
>
> Delmas : ils l’ont plié ? [En faisant le geste avec les mains]
>
> Eliahou : ouais [hoche la tête]
>
> Delmas : ils l’ont plié [Antoine : claque des mains] *rire de tous*
>
> Antoine : shiiiiiiiit [fait semblant de déchirer du papier]
>
> Matthieu : oh ca veut tout dire [se gratte le pied et se repenche
>   derrière] ouais c’est cool, ça c’est eh, ca c’est eh
>
> Eliahou : mais vous y êtes tous allés [montre tout le monde du doigt],
>   toi t’es allé, toi t’es allé ? //Delmas : oui moi j’y suis allé, j’y
>   vais depuis euh// //Matthieu : non [en hochant la tête]// et qu’est-ce
>   que tu attends alors ? [Matthieu : hoche les épaules]>> T’as fait ton
>   cv au moins ?ils prenaient ton cv là-bas non, pour les gars qui………
>
> Antoine : [croise les pieds] mais mais mais , moi j’ avais les cv pour
>   luiiiiiiii [ en donnant des points sur ses cuisses ] non mais , il beh
>   il marchait pour moi // Eliahou : ça c’ est vrai , il changeait juste
>   la photo // // Matthieu : attends mais il avait son son cv // oui
>   voilà , tu ne voudrais pas essayer ça ? [Donne un coup de coude à
>   Matthieu].
>
> Delmas : après les compétences euh ne sont pas les mêmes [Antoine :
>   ballait un coup de la main comme quoi ce n’est pas grave]
>
> Matthieu : ah beuh ouais
>
> Antoine : ouais mais mais t’as fait des maths dans ta jeunesse ?
>   [Hoche la tête et se tape à plusieurs reprises les cuisses] *rire de
>   tous *
>
> Delmas : t’as fait un peu’d C ? [Tendant la main vers Matthieu] >>
>   T’as fait un peu’d C ?
>
> Matthieu : ouais ouais j’ai fait un peu de C // Antoine : ouais
>   [baisse la tête et croise les mains sur ses genoux] // [serre ses
>   doigts]
>
> Eliahou : t’as fini d’écrire ta lettre ? [Regardant Matthieu et lui
>   tendant la main]// Antoine : t’as quand même euh, >> tu sais écrire
>   une lettre [tapote Matthieu], t’as >> fait une lettre à ta maman quand
>   même ?//
>
> Matthieu : je déteste ça, [regarde Antoine dans les yeux], [Eliahou se
>   mordille les ongles des doigts]*rire d’Antoine *// Delmas : voilà //
>
> Eliahou : et sinon les stages euh vous avez trouvé
>
> Antoine : moi je l’ai déjà
>
> Eliahou : et toi [montre Delmas du doigt] non mais toi t’as ton stage
>   en anglais
>
> Antoine : c’est vrai [en souriant]
>
> Delmas : non mais c’ est que l’ entretien , après euh c’ est pas sure
>   qu’ ils me prennent //Antoine : ouï tu m’ avais dit euh ch’ était cro
>   bizarre euh // si si c’ est bizarre [ se gratte le nez ] ( silence )
>
> Eliahou : non mais c’est pas fini la ? // Delmas : Non mais c’est
>   chaud hein // il reste combien de temps là ?
>
> Matthieu : on a rien à dire euh, et si on répétait ce qu’on avait dit
>   la dernière fois * rire de tous*
>
> Antoine : si si [se claque la cuisse] //Eliahou : et qu’est-ce qu’on
>   avait dit ? // qu’il y’ avait le psg , non mais c’ était le psg , vous
>   avez vu ? [Continu de se claquer les cuisses]
>
> Eliahou : ouais je l’ai vu
>
> Antoine : et alors ?
>
> Eliahou : ils ont perdu //Antoine : ah les Chelsea// contre Chelsea
>   //Matthieu : ouais je l’ai vu//
>
> Delmas : non mais euh ça pouvait pas être la dernière fois passeu euh
>   le match euh , il était mardi et s’ est enregistré euh * rire de tous
>   *
>
> Antoine : non mais euh, on a enregistré mardi
>
> Matthieu : on a enregistré lundi [se rapprochant d’Antoine]
>
> Delmas : à 10h * rire de tous * [manipulant un bonhomme en jouet entre
>   les mains]
>
> Antoine : oulaaaa *rire * il me regarde avec ses grands yeux [faisant
>   des grimaces] je vais te manger tout cru, tout nu non [se tape les
>   cuisses et faisant des grimaces ] * rire de tous *
>
> Matthieu : et tout ça il va falloir qu’on retranscrive * rire de tous
>   * // Antoine : c’est pas grave euh //
>
> Eliahou : [fait des gestes] non mais qu’est-ce qu’il est malade ce mec
>   *rire de tous *
>
> Antoine : [montre Delmas du doigt ] non mais dans les didascalies , on
>   mettra les grands yeux , tout cru tout nu , presque tout cru tout nu
>   [touche le jouet de Delmas ] comme BOB notre euh ….
>
> Eliahou : je vous propose de faire une petite dédicace à la prof pour
>   avoir une bonne note, on va parler de …
>
> Antoine : c’ est ça, cette vidéo c’est pour toi [montrant la caméra du
>   doigt]
>
> Matthieu : d’accord
>
> Eliahou : Tu te calmes [en souriant, regardant Antoine].
>
> Antoine : Tu te calmes [en faisant un signe de l’index réprobateur].
>   Bon d’accord.
>
> Eliahou : Faut parler d’un sujet là assez euh … Euh important,
>   intéressant. [les mains ouvertes, explicatives, les doigts écartés].
>
> Antoine : Les présidentielles américaines [fixant Eliahou, les mains
>   sur les genoux].
>
> Eliahou : Hein ?! (la tête s’approchant d’Antoine)
>
> Eliahou : Qu’est-ce que tu penses de …  [la main gauche se levant] //
>   [Matthieu tourne la tête]// Qu’est-ce que j’y connais moi en …
>   démocratie //Antoine : En démocratie pour moi c’est la même chose
>   [Antoine lève la main droite pour saluer une personne qui entre]// en
>   … républicain (bougeant les mains) je sais que Donald Trump il est
>   haut ? [levant la main gauche pour appuyer son propos] mais c’est un
>   milliardaire.
>
> Matthieu : C’est c’est un milliardaire.
>
> Antoine : [Salue à nouveau avec la main droite] Euh … On fait un
>   entretien.
>
> Eliahou : D’embauche.
>
> Matthieu : Ciao !
>
> Eliahou : L’affaire Aurier. [la main gauche ouverte, utilisant son
>   index pour commencer son propos]
>
> Antoine : C’est quoi l’affaire Aurier [interrogatif, se rapprochant de
>   Delmas] ?
>
> Eliahou : Ah ouais l’affaire Aurier rolala, Serge Aurier du PSG.
>
> Antoine : Le PSG ?
>
> Matthieu : Je sais que c’est consternant de débilité *rires*
>
> Antoine : Mais c’est quoi c’est quoi c’est quoi ? [se rapproche
>   d’Eliahou]
>
> Eliahou : Euuuh …
>
> Matthieu : Je n’ai pas dit
>
> Eliahou : Tu la connais toi l’histoire ? [tournant la tête vers
>   Antoine]
>
> Antoine : C’est un c’est un oui c’est un … [le pouce et le majeur
>   droit sur le menton, se creusant la tête]
>
> Eliahou : C’est comme Snapchat
>
> Matthieu : En live
>
> Eliahou : Ou voilà en en live
>
> *Delmas approuve en chuchotant*
>
> Antoine : Eh ben eh ben ?
>
> Eliahou : Eh ben il a mis une vidéo de 7/8 minutes //Matthieu : Où il
>   insultait. // où il insultait où il insultait voilà son coach son
>   entraîneur //Matthieu : Et après il s’est excusé, il a dit// ses
>   collègues //Matthieu : genre il a traité des gens de fiottes// voilà
>   //Matthieu : et dans la presse il a dit : « Je ne voulais pas dire
>   fiotte, je voulais dire PD ». D’accord, merci. *rires de tout le
>   monde* Excuse de malade.//
>
> Eliahou : Ça j’y crois pas trop [pointant son index vers Matthieu]
>
> Matthieu : Vraiment c’était écrit [haussant les sourcils] //Eliahou :
>   Y’a pas que ça aussi //
>
> Antoine : Et ce monsieur, c’était un joueur ? //Eliahou : Oui un
>   joueur de foot //
>
> Antoine : Pourquoi à chaque fois c’est [levant la main et la tapant
>   sur sa cuisse]
>
> Matthieu : Parce qu’ils sont joueurs … de FOOTeuh ! [en s’avançant
>   vers Antoine]
>
> Antoine : Bizarre ce qu’il se passe
>
> Eliahou : Je pense qu’il s’est mis tout le vestiaire à dos //Antoine :
>   Du coup// du coup il va plus jouer jusqu’à la fin de la saison
>   //Matthieu : Tant mieux //Antoine : Ben tant pis pour lui hein
>   [haussant les sourcils] //Eliahou : Mais c’est un très bon joueur //
>
> Antoine : Même si t’es beau, quand t’es con tu vas pas très loin
>   *rires*
>
> Eliahou : Ouais c’est vrai ça je sais pas… //Antoine : C’est pas //
>   j’ai pas envie de parler des gens politiques [envoie un baiser vers la
>   caméra] //Antoine : C’est pas russe Périscope parce que t’avais Maxime
>   … // //Matthieu : Pas du tout. Nan nan nan nan nan // //Antoine :
>   Bizarre, chelou [en abaissant la tête pour appuyer son propos]
>   //Matthieu : Maxime c’est juste qu’il a trouvé une fille sur Périscope
>   pendant le cours d’UML à poil qui était en train de se déshabiller
>   *rires de Matthieu et Eliahou*
>
> Antoine : Olalaaa … [mettant une main sur son visage] tu fais quoi
>   Maxime ? Parce que Maxime lorsqu’il travaille c’est //Eliahou : On va
>   faire la version non censurée hein [levant l’index pointant tout le
>   monde du doigt] *rires*
>
> Matthieu : Ça va être marrant
>
> Antoine : Tout s’est bien passé [appuyant son propos avec une main de
>   bas en haut sur la cuisse] *rire*
>
> Eliahou : Vous avez quoi là après tout à l’heure ? //Antoine : Bah
>   comme toi, réseaux [frappant sa main sur sa cuisse] ! // //Matthieu :
>   *parle doucement* On n’y va pas. //…// Moi aussi j’ai rien… Ah réseaux, c’est quoi ?
>
> Antoine : Réseaux, com… T’étais pas là ce matin ? Y’avait cours ce
>   matin de réseaux, il était pas là et du coup c’est toi qui est allé le
>   voir et il a fui Matthieu [pointant Matthieu avec son pouce droit] ?
>   //Matthieu : Nan pas du tout // mais… //Matthieu : Mais moi j’étais,
>   j’me suis pas réveillé//*rire*
>
> Antoine : nan moi je crois, nan c’est ça c’était Sarah… Sarah qui
>   avait fait  m’sieur m’sieur  [geste en levant le doigt vers le haut]
>   et lui il s’casse en courant [fait un geste de la main droite mimant
>   une personne qui court] *rire général*
>
> Delmas : c’était pas Sarah c’était moi en fait [rire de Matthieu en se
>   balançant sur sa chaise] en fait on a attendu déjà 40 minutes //
>   Antoine : ouai ouai // après on est monté chez Mathieu // Matthieu :
>   ils ont DEJA attendus 40 minutes [en s’adressant a Antoine]//
>   lorsqu’on est rentré on l’a vu il était avec une dame il avait l’air
>   euh décontracté [geste des mains imitant la décontraction] on lui a
>   dit « on avait cours » [pointant le doigt vers le haut en le faisant
>   trembler] alors il a dit ah ouais ??! [En prenant la voix de quelqu’un
>   d’étonné] *Rire général* // Antoine : nan mais il se fout de nous //
>   mais écoutez j’suis désolé euh *rigole* // Antoine : j’été pas au
>   courant [en frappant ses deux mains sur ses genoux en rigolant très
>   fort // je croyais qu’c’était entre midi et et et deux mais j’sais
>   pas.
>
> Eliahou : nan j’crois qui s’est pas réveillé c’est tout
>
> Matthieu : comme nous *rigole* // Antoine : p’tit croissant hein //
>   tant pis c’pas grave on n’ira pas c’est tout (…)
>
> Eliahou : moi personnellement j’dois faire mon sport [fait un geste de
>   la main en montrant une direction]
>
> Antoine : ah ouai c’est vrai lui il va à la salle c’est un sportif [en
>   montrant Eliahou du doigt]
>
> Eliahou : lui il fait l’marathon c’est un sportif aussi [en montrant
>   du doigt Antoine]
>
> Antoine : et et la salsa // Eliahou : ah ouai et la salsa *rigole* //
>   major major de la salsa [en pointant le doigt vers le haut] // Delmas
>   : avec 12 // [rire général et Antoine qui rigole en mettant ses deux
>   mains sur la figure] alors que là en communication [en montrant avec
>   sa main la salle de classe] quand ta 12 c’est la pire des notes alors
>   que là c’est la meilleur
>
> Delmas : ouai ouai
>
> Matthieu : c’est dl’a conneries
>
> Delmas : et encore j’pense qu’on qu’on va s’prendre au moins 17 là
>
> Antoine : PLUS [en élevant la voix, en serrant le poing puis le frappe
>   sur son genou] moi j’veux mille mille mille sûr [en tapant du poing
>   sur son genou à chaque répétition]

Comment: You are starting your script in the background (the `&` at the end). Then it seems it wants to have some input from the terminal (stdin), but it can't get it because it's in the background, that is why I think it stops. Try without the `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  wordssize=split(s,words,"%");
  if (wordssize==0) {
    words[1]=s;
    wordssize=1;
  }
  characterssize=0;
}
{
  if ($0 ~ /^ *[^:][^:]* *:/) {
    character=substr($1,1,index($0,":")-1);
    for (i=length(character);substr(character,i)==" ";i--){
        character=substr(character,1,length(character)-1);
    }
  }
  if (!lines[character]) {
    lines[character]=1;
    for(i=1; i<=wordssize; i++) {
      markers[words[i] " " character]=0;
    }
    characters[++characterssize]=character;
  } else {
    lines[character]++;
  }
  for(i=1; i<=wordssize; i++) {
    line=$0;
    while ((position=index(line,words[i]))>0) {
      markers[words[i] " " character]++;
      line=substr(line,position+length(words[i]));
    }
  }
}
END {
  printf("%9s %s","Character","Lines");
  for(i=1; i<=wordssize; i++) {
    printf(" %s", words[i]);
  }
  printf ("\n");
  for (i=1;i<=characterssize;i++) {
    printf("%9s %-5d",characters[i],lines[characters[i]],markers[characters[i]]);
    for(j=1; j<=wordssize; j++) {
      printf(" %-" length(words[j]) "d", markers[words[j] " " characters[i]]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
  }
}
```

If the current line starts with letters and **:**, the **character** variable is assigned the name found.
Each line of text is counted for each character.
Each time the sequence to search (e.g. **?**) is encountered, the marker counter of the character is incremented.

If a character speaks several lines, the above script will succeed to count the sequence, e.g. **?**, in the whole block of lines.

The string to search is specified with **-v s="?"**. Several strings can be searched at the same time. Separate the strings to search with **%**: **-v s="?%//"**.

The script can search several files at once if there are more than one filename.

In the output the characters are listed in the order of appearance.

The test:

```
$ chmod +x compteur
$ ./compteur -v s="?%//%'%t'es" Communication
Character Lines ? // ' t'es
  Antoine 2     0 1  0 0
  Eliahou 3     3 0  3 1
   Delmas 3     0 1  3 0

$ ./compteur -v s="?" Communication
Character Lines ?
  Antoine 2     0
  Eliahou 3     3
   Delmas 3     0
```

### ----

first version for history

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  if ($1 ~ /^[^:][^:]*:/) {
    character=substr($1,1,index($1,":")-1);
  }
  line=$0;
  lines[character]++;
  while ((position=index(line,s))>0) {
    markers[character]++;
    line=substr(line,position+length(s));
  }
}
END {
  printf("%9s %s %s","Character","Lines",s);
  for (character in lines) {
    printf("\n%9s %-5d",character,lines[character]);
    if (markers[character]) {
      printf(" %-3s",markers[character]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: FYI, `awk` scripts can be in files with a `#! /usr/bin/awk -f` shebang, and have access to a pre-defined ARGV array (e.g. `BEGIN { searchseq=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]}`.  i.e. there's no need to wrap them in a shell script - unless the shell script does extra stuff outside of `awk` (which is usually unnecessary, because `awk` can do most of what the shell can do and a lot that the shell can't).

Comment: @cas the answer has been edited. I cannot use ARGV to pass parameters, such as **s** in the script, right?

Comment: You can.  I even gave you an example of how to do it in my first comment.  `searchseq=ARGV[1]` in `awk` is equivalent to `searchseq="$1"` in sh.  and `delete ARGV[1]` in `awk` removes the first arg, same as `shift` does in sh.  GNU `awk` even has a library that provides `getopt()` for `awk` (with --long option capability as well as short options).  See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getopt-Function.html - but you don't really need `getopt` if you're just passing a single mandatory argument before the filename.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I understand now. I do not have gawk installed. So I prefer to let user explicitely pass parameter with **-v**, and let **awk** use the file arguments.

Comment: you misunderstood what i said.  Standard/POSIX `awk` has `ARGV[]`.  GNU `awk` **also** has a `getopt` library (which is not required for what you are doing).  `ARGV[]` is a pre-defined array that contains ALL of the script's arguments, same as `$1` ... `$9` etc in shell.

Comment: I got it alteady, sure, and I also tested it. I wanted anyway to leave this curent version unchanged where the **s** parameter is passed with **-v**.

Comment: Okay therfore this will list in the order of asking the lines and the people where the argument where present, isn't it?

Comment: @Marine1 I do not understand "in the order of asking". The argument **s** is the sequence of chars to search. For each character (or person) encountered, the number of lines and the number of times the sequence is found in these lines are both counted and they are printed at the end.

Comment: @Marine1: I believe it displays: Character, total_nb_of_lines_for_this_character, and number_of_occurence_of_the_searched_term . I may be wrong. A simpler invocation is with quotes: `./compteur -v s='?'` ,  and double quotes if you are looking for something containing a single quote: `./compteur -v s="'tit"` . Looking for `s=\'` should give a good approximation of the usage of ellipse, but catches also other things, like `j'ai`, which could be considered not an ellipse... ymmv.

Comment: @OlivierDulac this is all correct. thx !

Comment: @Marine1 A new version had been provided. The characters found are printed in the exact same order than the order of appearance in the text. The **s** variable accepts now more than one value. **%** is used to separate the strings to search, see the test for example.

Comment: @Jayjargot Still a big thanks for your script! Yet I don't understand what `lines[characters[i]]` is. Indeed, I tried with an actual document, and it answered me: `Antoine 203   31` for instance. What is `203`? I understand that the last number is how much time does the symbol given as an argument occur. Furthermore, as far as I asked `compteurQuestions -v s="?" exempleCommunication&` it answered me `Delmas 12    0`, yet I had "Delmas : t’as fait un peu’d C ?" in the text... Delmas did asked a question...

Comment: `lines[characters[i]]`: **characters[i]** is a table of names. **lines** is an associative array (or Map) which for a given key stores a value. All together, the result of this is the number of lines counted for the **ith** character. `203` is the number of lines counted for Antoine. I try to test the script with **Delmas** question and it is working, so I cannot troubleshoot your situation.

Comment: @Jayjargot , okay, thanks! Can you give a look to the actual text I added? It actually shows that Delmas asked a question and the output remains `Delmas 12 0`...

Comment: @Marine1 I am no more close to a computer. I will debug tomorrow with the text. It is night here in the french Alps.

Comment: @Jayjargot, it is too in Paris! Thanks and good night!

Comment: @Marine1 The text has too many variations for a simple program to count properly sentences of each character and strings. The script has been updated a little to take into account `Delmas  :` and `Delmas:` at start of a line. But still, there are the `Eliahou : Vous avez quoi là après tout à l’heure ? //Antoine : ...`. For this last version to work properly, take care to not mix several sentences from several character on the same line. Otherwise a much more complex program is needed.

Comment: @Jayjargot, I understand... It is to signify when somebody else barge in...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the shell variable `a` holds the string you are looking for and assuming that this string is never part of any person's name (if it is, the `grep`-pattern needs to be extended to match only after the first `:`) and assuming that `:` is never part of any person's name and assuming that `a` does not contain a newline:

`cat Communication | grep -F "${a}" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c`

Do not escape the contents of `a`, because there is the `-F`-option for `grep`. Content of `a` is taken literally (as long as it doesn't contain a newline).

If the names of the person can contain the string you are looking for, the following works, but then keep in mind to escape any characters in `a` which can have special pattern-matching meaning for `grep` (i.e. if you look for `.`, but `\.` into `a`, if you look for `?`, use `\?`, etc.):

`cat Communication | grep -E "^[^:]*:.*${a}" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c`

Or, in particular, answers to three of your sub-questions:

> who asks questions (who have a "?" in their quote), how much time

`cat Communication | grep -F '?' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c`

> who cut someone off, (who have a "//" in their quote)

`cat Communication | grep '//' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c`

> who does some elision ("t'es" instead of "tu es" ("you're" instead of "you are") and at which frequency...

`cat Communication | grep "'" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c`

(I know all of those are "useless use of cat", but it makes the flow of data more clear to first `cat` and then pipe into `grep`. One can also use `grep -F "${a}" Communication | [...]` etc. instead)